# Ionic tabs text color to be set differently for active and inactive tabs

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, tabs

I used ionic tab in my app and i need to change the color of tab icon title color for active and inactive tabs. I have tried some CSS but ended up without the solution. I need different colors for each tab title when selected.

Comment: Please post your code in fiddle too so we can check and try to help. Without code we can't help.

Comment: Please add some code or a demo link that shows your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative.

```
<!-- pages/tabs/tabs.html -->
<ion-tabs color="dark" tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Todo"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Plannificator"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Schedler"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="About"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>



// themes/variables.scss
.tabs-md .tab-button {
  color: #FFC400 !important;
 }

 .tabs-md .tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
   color: #DD2C00 !important;
 }
```

[image: Main Application]

Answer (score 0):

For getting different colors on each tab when it is placed you need to make changes in two files.

you need to add some custom class in your tabs.html file like displayed below:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" class="dash" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" class="chat" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" class="account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

In above code **class="dash"**, **class="chat"** and **class="account"** these are extra added classes.

Now in your **/scss/ionic.app.scss** file you need to enter below mentioned lines:

```
.tab-item.dash.tab-item-active, .tab-item.dash.active, .tab-item.dash.activated {
    color: $energized !important;
}

.tab-item.chat.tab-item-active, .tab-item.chat.active, .tab-item.chat.activated {
    color: $balanced !important;
}

.tab-item.account.tab-item-active, .tab-item.account.active, .tab-item.account.activated {
    color: $calm !important;
}
```

Hope this will help you !